# Access vba Runtime Error 91 - fails one time only

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Question: Is there a known Access/VBA issue where one gets error 91 and then once manually continuing to run the code via Debug/F5 (without changing anything) the error no longer comes up?

This is a large project and I am not sure what is causing this error. I know is not a variable that is not set, because I only get the error once. Here is the scenario:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Assume an Access 2010 .accdb file (split forms).
2. I open the application and press a button that is calling a number of functions to accomplish a certain goal. The functions create various class instances, access the database (via DAO recordset and db.execute SQL updates). The sequence of functions read data from a table and update another table based on some predefined business logic. Assuming the data in the source table is not changing, pressing the button will always result in SAME data being processed, and the same code sequence - I am trying to establish that the first and the subsequent button presses do not change in any way the program flow.

Behavior:

1. First time I press the button after launching the application, I invariably get the error 91.
2. Upon getting the error, I enter debug mode (pressing the 'Debug' button)
3. Once in debug mode, all I have to do is press F5 to continue running the program, and that no longer throws the runtime error 91, and the operation completes without issues.
4. Any subsequent button presses work without any error.

I am not sure this is relevant, But here is the line of code where the debugger takes me, and that function it calls:

```
If Not DBUpdate(strSQL, Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule, "DBLocked", "") Then Exit Function


Public Function DBUpdate(str_SQL As String, str_Module As String, Optional str_Function As String, Optional str_ErrorDetails As String) As Boolean
    Dim booDBUpdateFail As Boolean
    Dim intFailCount As Integer
    DBUpdate = True 'assume success
    intFailCount = 0
    On Error GoTo DBUpdateError
    Do
        booDBUpdateFail = False
        db.Execute str_SQL, dbFailOnError
    Loop Until booDBUpdateFail = False Or intFailCount = P_DBUpdateRetriesOnFailure
    If intFailCount = P_DBUpdateRetriesOnFailure Then DBUpdate = False  'return failure
    Exit Function
DBUpdateError:
    intFailCount = intFailCount + 1
    modIO.AppendToDBLog CStr(Now()) & ": " & str_Module & " - ErrorDBExecute - " & str_Function & " - " & str_ErrorDetails & " - TryCount: " & CStr(intFailCount)
    booDBUpdateFail = True
    Wait P_DBUpdateRetryIntervalSeconds * 1000 'wait
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Note: DB above is a public object instantiated by the On Load event of a hidden form that starts when the application starts. Initialization sub:

```
Public Sub InitPublic()
    If db Is Nothing Then Set db = CurrentDb() 'Open connection to current Access database
    If UserPerm Is Nothing Then Set UserPerm = New clsUserPerm
    If wfstatus Is Nothing Then Set wfstatus = New clsWFStatus
    If Log Is Nothing Then Set Log = New clsLog
    If PurchaseLevels Is Nothing Then Set PurchaseLevels = New clsPurchasingLevels
    If objPrintTemplate Is Nothing Then Set objPrintTemplate = New clsPrintTemplate
    If objPrintReport Is Nothing Then Set objPrintReport = New clsPrintTemplate
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the VBE opened before you press the button for the first time? Because you are trying to access `Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule` that might not exist if VBE is not opened (and once you are in debug mode, VBE is opened, so F5 and subsequent calls are working).

Comment: Hi Vincent, Thanks for pointing that out. It was the VBE indeed. Feeling quite stupid right now... :)

Comment: Do you know of a way I can get the current module (and ideally the function/sub name) at run-time (without VBE being open)? I need it for silently logging errors, and don't want to type the module and function name every time.